# How do I run a React App without JS Node just vanilla VSC for a class

Tags: javascript, java, html, node.js, reactjs

Trying to open the below files with Chrome and it is blank. What am I doing wrong? I am trying to link the js file and use it to display an h1 but for some reason can not wrap my head around it.

Only two files

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <title>React App</title>
      <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
      script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>
    </head>


    <body>
      <div id="root"></div>

      <script src="main.js"></script>
    </body>
  </html>
```

main.js

```js
function tick() {
    const element = (
        <div>
          <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
          <h2>It is {new Date().toLocaleTimeString()}.</h2>
        </div>
    );

    ReactDOM.render(
       element,
       document.getElementById('root')
    );
}

setInterval(tick, 1000);
```

Comment: The third `script` tag does not spell correctly (should start with <)? Is it a misscopy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.) first thing first babel script tag is not opened and closed properly.

```
script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>
```

it should be like below:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
```

2.) you also need to specify type babel in your script which have JSX/react code:

```
<script type="text/babel" src="">
```

3.) **(Imp.) Your Any react Component must start with a Capital letter.**
I have used the function as react component to render which returns the JSX code. and kept the RenderDOM out of the React component.
if I have to refactor your code:

```
 function Tick() {
    return  (
  <div>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
    <h2>It is {new Date().toLocaleTimeString()}.</h2>
  </div>
     );
     
     

     }

    
     ReactDOM.render(
        <Tick />,
          document.getElementById('root')
            );
```